# Language to DFA

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-expressions

Be $F_k$ a language over $\Sigma = \{0, 1, \#\}$ of the form: 
$L_k = \{v\#uvw | u, v, e \in \{0, 1\}^*, |v| \leq k\}$. 
Show that for each k: $L_k$ is regular by constructing a DFA for $L_k$. 
The DFA is to be drwan for k=2.

My problem is that I don't know how to tackle this problem. I have only drawn DFAs for languages of the form $L_k = \{w | $some regular expression or textual condition$\}$ and I can't really find an example of such a language converted to a DFA.

Am I to draw a DFA for $v\#uvw$ or $\{0,1\}^*$?

Comment: It might help to convert the language description to natural language first.  For k=2 the string will be.  (Between 0 to 2 characters from "0","1") followed by "#" followed by any number of characters from "0","1" followed by exactly the string that was before # then ending with any number of character from "0","1".

Comment: Thanks, I think I know now how to go about this. I'll give it a try.